# Create New table from Df that shows count of one column and a arithmetic of another column

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the image of the df structure I have:
[image]

I need to create a new df that shows the following:

First column : Posting Date
Second Column: No of entries (basically counts how many entries there are on a particular date
3rd Column: Sums of all 'ADR' on a particular date and then divides by the second column value for that date

How can this be done?

Here is my current code:

```
posting_df4 = posting_df4.groupby(['Posting_date']).count()
```

But this only counts the column info and I do not know how to proceed to add another column that does the arithmetic of the 3rd column mentioned.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
s1 = posting_df4.groupby(['Posting_date'])['Posting_date'].transform('count')
s2 = posting_df4.groupby(['Posting_date'])['ADR'].transform('sum')
posting_df4['new'] = s2 / s1
```